# Fail when building wheel for pycrypto, how can I fix that problem?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I wanted to install the "machine" module so that I can use specific functions related to the hardware but when I entered the command "python -m pip install machine", I got an issue when building wheel for pycrypto as presented on the following image [the error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ya0c.png)

As I've seen Pycrypto was considered obsolete I installed pycryptodome instead but it did nothing about it.

Comment: it says on the official docs *"This projects does not aim to cover best practices for Python project development as a whole. For example, it does not provide guidance or tool recommendations for version control, documentation, or testing."*...

Comment: here are the docs...  https://pypi.org/project/machine/